# How can I add meta data to the head section of the page from a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin and need to add some meta tags to the head section of the page from within my plugin. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can add an action hook to `wp_head` like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', myCallbackToAddMeta);
function myCallbacktoAddMeta(){
  echo "\t<meta name='keywords' content='$contents' />\n";
}
```

Comment: This works but only if you do this on top of the plugin. Is there a way you can do something similar but within a loop lets say you are looping in some special offers and for every individual entry you want custom meta tags.... As I have tried it but to no avail :(